# What is the word or idiom equivalent to henpecked?

Tags: idioms, vocabulary

This is the meaning of hen-pecked from urban dictionary:

When a male complies to ever single demand of his girlfriend or wife, and the female is in complete control of her man. A hen-pecked male will easily sell out to his woman and blow off his friends. Also see Pussy-whipped.
please tell me the other idiom or word with the same meaning.

Comment: Erm... "henpecked" *is* an idiom. An approximately equivalent standard term is ["uxorious"](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/uxorious)

Comment: *Henpecked* is considerably dated and would nowadays be seen as extraordinarily sexist, if for no other reason than its tendency to role stereotyping.

Comment: You have to be careful with definitions you find in *Urban dictionary*. Since they can be written by anybody, they are often inaccurate, hyperbolic, sarcastic, offering more of a paraphrase than a definition,  etc—and sometimes plain wrong. I'd use a good standard dictionary such as Oxford Dictionary online.

Answer (score 2):

**[Submissive/browbeaten](http://www.vocabulary.com/dictionary/hen-pecked#word=henpecked)**- TFD mentions...

- *inclined or willing to submit to orders or wishes of others* or showing such inclination.

Answer (score 2):

Tied by (or to) her apron strings

Comment: Welcome to ELU. It's a good answer and I've upvoted it. Please make it better by adding some references to help other users. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Along the same line...[wife-ridden](https://www.wordnik.com/words/wife-ridden):

> - Unduly influenced by a wife; ruled or tyrannized over by a wife; henpecked.

Answer (score 1):

A more general idiom of subservience is *[under the thumb](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/under+the+thumb)* (or *under one's thumb*)

> under control :  in a state of subservience: *her father did not have her that much under his thumb* — Hamilton Basso

*Merriam-Webster*

[Mr. Jagger](http://www.azlyrics.com/lyrics/rollingstones/undermythumb.html) has commented on both being the thumber and the thumbee

> The way she talks when she's spoken to
>
> Down to me, the change has come,
>
> She's under my thumb
>
> Yeah, it feels alright
>
> Under my thumb

*azlyrics.com*

by Mick Jagger and Keith Richards